# How do I move an individual vertex in AFrame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, cad, webvr

In Three.js I could use:

```
myObject.geometry.vertices[i].y += 12;
```

but in A-Frame nothing is even visible in console.log.
I had seen where between 0.2.0 and 0.3.0 everything
defaults to to buffer geometry and vertices were hidden.
Overriding this was possible, but now in 0.5.0 not even
the geometry array is listed in console.log.

```
console.log(myObject.geoetry); //now returns 'undefined'.
console.log(myObject); //returns the markup only, no array!?
```

Is there currently a way to address individual vertices to change their positions?

Answer (score 2):

Set `geometry="buffer: false"`.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/geometry.html#base_properties_buffer

Then get the geometry:

`el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry`

Comment: Thanks! I was just browsing http://ngokevin.com/blog/aframe-component/ about an hour ago.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined.. which is weird, because: this.el.setObject3D('mesh', new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));   works just fine, and is able to import older code from three.js.

Comment: Trying to drop vertices 0-7 and 80,  and 72-79 and 81 down. Assuming 80&81 are the vertices in the centers of the ends, like cylinder geometry has them placed in THREE.js. I know the partial torus starts on the right and arcs to the left, because I built it at a lower arc than 180 to start with. Actually, in three.js I set it to 1 to check direction before bumping it up to PI.

Comment: Quick JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/RonK/tjfwhdsd/22

Comment: this is strange, when I add geometry="buffer: false" to my custom plane created with vertices, it converts the plane into a box. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67212305/manipulate-vertices-on-the-go-in-aframe